# Microservices structure with Laravel

Tags: laravel, microservices

I have to dev a project with 5 microservices by now, but in a future it could have more than 50. And I have a big problem with the auth.

All microservices need auth to access to the information, here is the problem.

How I can do it?.

I thought some like that:

- ms1.blabla.com
- ms2.blabla.com
- ...
- auth.blabla.com

Make an "auth" microservice and here store users, pass, tokens, and other stuffs.

It is ok? or any other suggestion?

Another problem is how I get the data from others services? I need to call every time to auth microservice in ms1 microservice before the fetch the data to check the token? like a middleware in every microservices?... It sounds very awful and making a lot of requests to auth.

Any know how to do it in the best way? some tutorial, example, packages, idk. Any idea is well receive.

Another problem is if use Laravel or Lumen (?). I thought Laravel on every project to make it more scalable in time, and the front-end in Vue. Or just Lumen cuz it now is just database and data, no more.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

if you need to handle auth in your API I really suggest relying on Passport (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) to handle authorization instead of building something from your own.

Regarding the choice of Laravel Vs Lumen it depends on how you plan to handle the frontEnd. Lumen is just a simpler / faster version of Laravel but you won't be able to handle session, cookies, etc.
If you are making requests to your microservices from several frontends (for example a website and a mobile app) I suggest to use Lumen and build only an API. You can find a more detailled article on differences between both here https://medium.com/@jeffalmeida_27473/laravel-vs-lumen-what-should-i-use-63c196822b2d